# Find mouse cursor dependent on windows form(not all screen)

Tags: c#, mousemove

(Maybe there is a topic in this, but unfortunately I can't find it)

How can I find mouse coordinate dependent to windows form ?

Below code in c# can show mouse coordinate :

```
    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        label1.Text = string.Format("X: {0} , Y: {1}", Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
    }
```

But this code show the coordinate in whole screen, when I want the coordinate (0,0) be top-left side of my form!

And I know that i can use [Cursor.Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx) and [PointToClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) , but I cant solve my problem with them. can any one help me with several lines code?

(I use windows form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [MouseEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs.aspx) passed to your event there is a property called [`Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.location.aspx).
According to MSDN

> A Point that contains the x- and y- mouse coordinates, in pixels,
>   relative to the upper-left corner of the form.

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    label1.Text = string.Format("X: {0} , Y: {1}", e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);
}
```

Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Excuse me , but I confused! can you explain more what should I do please?

Comment: Added your code, revised to use the Location property passed inside the MouseEventArgs parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much, you solved my problem! 
This code work great and no more code need.